# Usando Unicode em uma variavel char

Tags: c, char, byte, unicode

Galera como eu faço pra usar `unicode` em `C`? Eu só não sei como armazenar os 2 bytes de um `unicode` em um char, só isso, alguém sabe como?

Comment: 2 bytes nao chegam para todos os elementos do Unicode!

Comment: Eu preciso de uma bitagem para caracteres latinos e japoneses, isso seria então 3 bytes? hm

Answer (score 3):

`wchar_t seu_caractere = L'\u1234'`

---

Existem outros tipos de dados para caracteres customizados, como o `char32_t`. Mas no seu caso, é fácil de lidar com o problema usando o *wide char*.